# ng-select `set selectedid` variable to 0 if value not found

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I am using ng-select provided from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

is there a way in this , that if user types in a value which is not present in the options then set the `selectedid` variable to 0

Let say this control is binding to below array

```
{
    'id': '5a15b13c36e7a7f00cf0d7cb',
    'name': 'John',
},

{
    'id': '523675b13c36e7a7f00cf0d7cb',
    'name': 'Doe',
},
```

if the user types in something like "Apple", then the `selectedid` variable declared in TS file should be set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[addTag]="true"` and then use event `change` to set all custom value ids to `0`.

I provided a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-bybgqa) to explain it better.

Comment: i am using single select and not multiselect . using this component,  when user selects any value present in options then the `selectedId` variable is set to the selected item id.

What i want is when user types in search textbox and the typed value is not present in options, then `selectedId` variable value should be set to 0.

Comment: I updated the stackblitz @Pankaj

Comment: Was it helpful?! @Pankaj

Comment: Application not compiling 

`Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'`

even in your stackbiltz example its showing same error at line number 55,56 and 58

Comment: define type of any for that @Pankaj

Comment: let selectedId: any = {};

Comment: i am trying this with some more to it example i am making this as a reusable component and emitting the selected value to the parent component. I will surely let you know if this works or not.